# Aggregating column totals in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
variable1 <- c(1,1,1,0,1,0)
variable2 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,0)
variable3 <- c(1,0,1,0,1,1)

df <- data.frame(variable1, variable2, variable3)
```

What is the easiest way to get a dataframe output that looks like this:

```
   Variable     Total
   Variable1     4
   Variable2     2
   Variable3     3
```

`colsums` kind of gets me there, but the variable names aren't output as a legitimate column using this method.

Comment: Summarize and pivot. Or pivot and then summarize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    summarise(Total = sum(value))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  name      Total
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 variable1     4
2 variable2     2
3 variable3     4
```

Comment: this is the first answer I tried and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This could be another option:

```
df %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>%
  janitor::adorn_totals()

    id variable1 variable2 variable3
     1         1         0         1
     2         1         0         0
     3         1         0         1
     4         0         1         0
     5         1         1         1
     6         0         0         1
 Total         4         2         4
```

Comment: Janitor comes to rescue many times in everyday use

Answer (score 2):

Using `stack/colSums`

```
stack(colSums(df))[2:1]
        ind values
1 variable1      4
2 variable2      2
3 variable3      4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
variable1 <- c(1,1,1,0,1,0)
variable2 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,0)
variable3 <- c(1,0,1,0,1,1)

df <- data.frame(variable1, variable2, variable3)
> data.frame(Total= colSums(df))
          Total
variable1   4
variable2   2
variable3   4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
## data frame
variable1 <- c(1,1,1,0,1,0)
variable2 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,0)
variable3 <- c(1,0,1,0,1,1)

df <- data.frame(variable1, variable2, variable3)
df

##using dplyr Library
library(dplyr)
new_df = df %>% summarise(across(variable1:variable3,sum)) # sum of ones in each column
t(new_df) # transpose new_df to get desired pattern
```

Comment: Welcome Sakshi to SO! typing `sum` for each variable again and again is not encouraged.  Use `dplyr::across` in these cases. :)

Comment: @AnilGoyal Thanks for the information. I have made the edit.

Answer (score 1):

one more approach can be

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), sum)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything())

#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   name      value
#>   <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 variable1     4
#> 2 variable2     2
#> 3 variable3     4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>